# Alphabetically sort JQM list view?

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

i have a JSON in forma key - value:

```
{
"535826": "Adamov",
"536156": "Bečice",
"544272": "Borek",
"544281": "Borovany",
"535681": "Borovnice",
"544299": "Boršov nad Vltavou",
"535401": "Bošilec",
"551490": "Branišov",
"536059": "Břehov"
}
```

If i display source code of this writeout is everything sorted as above, aplhabeticaly.

Problem is, if I used   **jQuery.ajax**

In this case are returned values sorted ordered by ID, for example 536059

I writing on Jquery mobile list, ad so i cannot use sort method like

```
//SORT UNORDERED LIST  - NOT USED 
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
      if(typeof ul == "string")
        ul = document.getElementById(ul);

      // Idiot-proof, remove if you want
      if(!ul) {
        alert("The UL object is null!");
        return;
      }

      // Get the list items and setup an array for sorting
      var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
      var vals = [];

      // Populate the array
      for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

      // Sort it
      vals.sort();

      // Sometimes you gotta DESC
      if(sortDescending)
        vals.reverse();

      // Change the list on the page
      for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
    }
```

Exist any easy solutions for this?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the map is that it is inherently unsorted. Do you have control over the source? You could generate a list of key/value pairs, in which the order would be maintained:

```
[{"535826": "Adamov"},
{"536156": "Bečice"},
{"544272": "Borek"},
{"544281": "Borovany"},
{"535681": "Borovnice"},
{"544299": "Boršov nad Vltavou"},
{"535401": "Bošilec"},
{"551490": "Branišov"},
{"536059": "Břehov"}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have no controll over the source.